Print parquet size while using Flink FileSink.forBulkFormat
I am using 1.17 Flink and I want to print the size of parquets that FileSink creates.
I am using forBulkFormat.
I need an indication for parquets size that I am uploading to blob storage for monitoring.
FileSink.forBulkFormat(s3SinkPath, new ParquetWriterFactory<>(builder))
                    .withBucketAssigner(new CustomDateTimeBucketAssigner())
                    .withRollingPolicy(new OnCheckpointRollingPolicy())
                    .build(); 



The only solution I found is the link I attached but because some of the fileSink classes declared as internal I can't implement this solution in advance Flink version like 1.17 using this        link
